# pom.properties customisation in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, properties-file, manifest.mf

Maven generates a `pom.properties` file inside `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}` than contains the version, groupId and artifactId.

Can I add my own entries?

If would like to manage information like SVN url, site url, etc. in the artifact. Besides the `MANIFEST.MF`, the `pom.properties` seems to be an obvious place for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pom.properties` is generated by [maven-archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html). You can not add entries. But what you can make to create your own.

I would suggest to put such information into `MANIFEST.MF` file instead which can be configured via attributes in the pom file.